# ext.net calendar customisation

Tags: ext.net

i am trying to write my own application and using the ext,net.

i am trying to add the calendar of ext.net from the ext.examples.net (remote data )

how can i , when creating a new event, 1st i want to add more fields than the class event contains.

and i want to customize the pop up window when editing , or creating a new event. so i would be able to add all the custom fields that i want and resave in database.

or if it is possible to change all the form that goes pop up, for the add, edit , new events.

any way to d3o that?

REGARDS

Comment: on the default ext.net calender that can be downloaded from the ext.net.examples.
when clicking on event day or range event or edit an event, ...a pop up window is pushed on ,where we can edit add ,modify date edit 
details on an event ...
what am asking that is it better to add to that form custom fiealds or to create another form and then lunch it on those events, and if so how can that be done and btw what is pastebin.com and how that can be helpfull ??

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by extending Ext.Net.DateField control.

For changing control rendering  and adding custom fields to control you have to inherit from Ext.Net.DateField class and write own ExtJs extenstion for ExtJs DateField.

For changing Events you have to extend Ext.Net.DateFieldListeners and add them to your new control. Of course, you have to add appropriate code to ExtJs control extension.

To do that you can look through Ext.NET source code.

But this is not easy.

More easy in some ways is to just override css and add extraparameters to DirectEvent or DirectMethods. If you want to add some properties to instance of  control you can use CustomConfig property. And if some logic of your control is working not as much as you want you can override it by ExtJs Ext.override method.

Comment: is it better to create a new form that contains all the fields that i need,and attach this form on handlers.?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't clearly understand what you mean. Can you show me some your code? You can do that via pastebin.com.